# Blender assign armature to mesh: “bone heat weighting failed to find solution for one or more bones”

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I get this error working with Blender while I try to assigning armature's bones to an human mesh.

Comment: Please don't answer the question in the question itself, use the *Answer Question* button to [answer your own question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in an *Answer*. Thanks.

Comment: I can't, for reputations limit!

Comment: @velthune You have the privilege to answer questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The OP originally posted this in their question.

If it happened to you too and you were looking for any solution, I solved in this way:

- select mesh in edit-mode;
- in the bar "Mesh tools" select the voice "Remove Doubles" (that remove duplicate vertex).

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZPqxADetWE) there's a video that explain the procedure.

Another way to solve the problem would be add a modifier to the mesh:

- "Decimate" modifier.

Comment: thanks men, it helped me alot :)
the first procedure worked on me
just press ctr+v when selecting all vertices in the mesh and choose remove doubles